# Error with autoload.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

in My laravel application when I try to php artisan serve command it is generating following error msg in the cmd.

> Warning:require:failed to open streem: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Hema\Desktop\larablog\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

this is My autoload.php line 17

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: you can fix it by running `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `composer install`? Without the autoloader generated by composer it probably won't work.

You learn more about composer here:
https://getcomposer.org/